# Add an event handler to a Telerik RadGrid from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I want to add a client-side JavaScript event handler that will fire each time a row is selected or deselected on an ASP.NET Telerik RadGrid and **I need to add it from JavaScript without server-side code.** How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just do it while declaring the grid? `<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
    <ClientSettings>
        <ClientEvents OnRowSelecting="RowSelecting" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>`

Comment: I unfortunately only have access to JavaScript on the page. The rest is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **RadAjaxManager**.
ASPX:

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" 
            onajaxrequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest"></telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onclientrowclick(sender, args) {

        $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest();
    }
 </script>
```

C#:

```
 protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
    {
            //your code
    }
```

EDIT:

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowMultiRowSelection="true"  >
      <ClientSettings Selecting-AllowRowSelect="true">
      <ClientEvents OnRowSelecting="OnRowSelecting" OnRowDeselecting="OnRowDeselecting" />
      </ClientSettings>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

JS:

```
 function OnRowDeselecting(sender, args) {
        alert("deselect");
    }
    function OnRowSelecting(sender, args) {
        alert("select");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that I want to call a JavaScript function. The page is compiled, so I can't add an event handler like this.

Comment: I didnt get you . you need to fire an event in server side right?

Comment: No, I need to fire a client-side, JavaScript event. Something like whenever someone selects a row, a function is called and an array of the selected rows is passed.

Comment: For that you can use OnRowSelecting and OnRowDeselectingevent in radgrid

Comment: Would you please show me how to do that? The accepted answer will be in 100% JavaScript. I have no access to server-side technology.

Comment: Yeah, I can't do that because I can't edit the ASPX page. I've only got access to JavaScript. Thanks for trying though!